# Add Persian to Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, ibus, input-language, input-method

How can I add Persian to Xubuntu?
It is an interesteing point, Xubuntu supports Persian language, and the titles and menu change to Persian. But, I did not find any where yet, to change the INPUT LANGUAGE to Persian. It means the option which permits you to type in Persian. 
Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Install the *ibus-m17n* package, log out from the session, and log in again. Then you should be able to select Persian from IBus Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the existing answer, to install `ibus-m17n` one can do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
```